# Visibility="Private" cmdlets can be retrieved from a function

Tags: security, powershell, scripting

I am providing my customers the ability to script with PowerShell in my application but I want to severely restrict the commands they can use.  Setting Visibility to Private for cmdlets works for the top scope, but if you wrap the command in a function it's available again.  Why does this work?  Should the visibility still be private in the function so I can't execute the cmdlet?

```
PS C:\> Get-Process -name "firefox"

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
470      53   143336     141720   390     5.71  18380 firefox


PS C:\> Get-Command -name "Get-Process" | % { $_.Visibility = "Private" }
PS C:\> Get-Process -name "firefox"

The term 'Get-Process' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:12
+ Get-Process <<<<  -name "firefox"
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-Process:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
_________________

PS C:\> function getp { Get-Process -name "firefox" }<br/>
PS C:\> getp

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
    470      53   143336     141720   390     5.71  18380 firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

You've only changed the visibility of `Get-Process` from the top level scope. The name of the function in the lower level scope (inside `getp`) sees `get-process` at a different scope and so is not private. As per the [help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx):

```
Private:
    Items in private scope cannot be seen outside of the current
    scope. You can use private scope to create a private version
    of an item with the same name in another scope.
```

If you have a set of functions that you want to only selectively make visible I think you might be better off using [modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Say you have a module with a bunch of functions - `scopes.psm1`:

```
function write-private { "From Private Func."}
function write-public { "From Public Func." }
export-modulemember -function public-func
```

since only `write-public` is exported, it is the only function visible. Then the person importing it can only call that:

```
# > Import-Module .\scopes.psm1

# > write-private
write-private : The term 'write-private' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ write-private
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (write-private:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


# > write-public
From Public Func.
```

Comment: This makes sense, but the modules will probably not help out our current needs.  This would still allow users that are writing the functions into our system to call cmdlets that we do not want them to have access to.

Also, even when the cmdlet is set to private, it works in the function it is called in even though we can still see that it shows as private.

`PS C:\> Get-Command -name "Get-Process" | % { $_.Visibility = "Private" }
PS C:\> function checkvis { Get-Command -name "Get-Process" | % { $_.Visibility }}
PS C:\> checkvis
Private`